# Не удается найти указанный файл Git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash

При нажатии на иконку GitBash выдает каждый раз из меню windows выдает КАЖДЫЙ раз вот это оповещение!(см фото) Как его убрать навсегда? 
Сам GIT bash после ОК запускается и работает нормально.

[image: При нажатии на иконку GitBash выдает каждый раз]

Может ли это быть от того, что я устанавливала его на диск D, а не С? 
Тем не менее все файлы он все равно гонит на С

Comment: Правый клик на иконке GitBash - Свойства - Ярлык - Сменить значок

Comment: То же самое выдает после смены значка.

Comment: Убрать русский и любой другой, отличный от английского, язык в имени каталога, и самое главное— убрать пробелы в именах каталога.

Comment: 0andriy, спасибо! урааа, все получилось!!!! Спасибоо!

Comment: Новое дополнение!

Answer (score 0):

В имени каталога для инсталяции Git желательно использовать только ASCII (латинские) символы без пробелов. Переименуйте каталог.