# GIT bash HERE выдает "приложение не найдено"

Tags: git, git-bash

Внезапно команда GIT bash HERE выдает (см. скрин), при этом из меню запускается нормально.
SOS, как восстановить???
P.s. до этого папка гита была перенесена в другое место
P.p.s значок гита из плиток пропал

[image: Внезапно команда GIT bash HERE выдает]

Comment: Вы его-таки [доломали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775119/213987)? ;) Попробуйте переустановить приложение.

Comment: неа не хочу переустанавливать, долго настраивать потом( попробую восстановить папку(

Comment: Можно не восстанавливать обратно пути, а сделать симлинк, это быстрее.

Comment: не помогло восстановление, как сделать симлинк?