# Git не находит папку, которой нет

Tags: git, git-bash

У меня даже и папки такой нет, что ему не нравится?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально была такая же проблема ([Не удается найти указанный файл Git Bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775119/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-git-bash)  )
Я переименовала папку, чтобы не было русских символов в пути папки.
Проблема пропала, как и гит через пару часов после того, как я его переместила.
Переустановила гит. 
опять то же самое.

Решение найдено.

ПКМ, перейти к расположению файла, ПКМ, свойства, сменить ярлык, заходите в скрытую системой папку Program Data на диске С, ищите там Git , заходите, ищите там ярлык гита, ок.

главное, не забыть скопировать расположение ярлыка в строку Обьект

Все бы отлично, но с bash here проблема осталась, выдает то, что на скрине приложила.
И вот как это последнее изменить-уже ума не приложу.

Comment: В пути к папке `Git` есть русские символы "`Проги ит`"

Comment: у меня нет такой папки вообще

Comment: Я переименовала папку, неск дней назад, чтобы не было русских символов в пути папки.  Теперь папки проги ит нет, я ее переименовала в транслит

Comment: @Rtototam, напиши ответ в ответ, а не в вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy но это половина решения, вторая часть под вопросом и остается

Comment: @Rtototam, ну так напиши обе в ответ.

Comment: @Rtototam полный снос и новая установка не даёт результатов?

Comment: @webDev_  неа, не дает.

Comment: Сохранил где-то в локальных настройках пользователя. Искать где-то в районе *C:\%USER%\Data Files\...\etc\...* (Я не помню названий специальных каталогов, не работаю в Windows, но идея думаю понятна)

Comment: 0andriy, что именно искать?